# How do I convert this example Savon 1 code into Savon 2?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I tried running this code from Ryan Bates's ruby cast but it doesn't work. I think it assumes the use of Savon 1.

```
require "savon"

client = Savon::Client.new("http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")
response = client.request :web, :get_info_by_zip, body: { "USZip" => zip }  
if response.success?  
   data = response.to_array(:get_info_by_zip_response, :get_info_by_zip_result, :new_data_set, :table).first  
   if data  
     @state = data[:state]  
     @city = data[:city]  
     @area_code = data[:area_code]  
     @time_zone = data[:time_zone]

     puts @state
     puts @city
     puts @area_code
   end  
 end
```

What is the correct implementation for Savon 2? I would like to copy and paste it and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from my Service-Wrapper class providing the SOAP-Services to other ruby objects. I initialize the client by providing the WSDL location and an own method for each SOAP operation. The thirdparty method is invoked with @client.call passing a block which creates a SOAP message with provided params.

```
  class Client
    include Singleton

    def wsdl_method_to_call
      begin
        response = @client.call(:wsdl_method_to_call) do
          message auth:CREDENTIALS, param_1: param_1_value, param_2: param_2_value
        end
      rescue
        raise CustomServiceException.new("Error ... , response : #{response}")
      end
    end


    def initialize()
      @client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: WSDL)
    end

    private
    WSDL = "http://service_host/wsdl"
    CREDENTIALS = "foo|bar"

  end
```

so maybe you should try something like:

```
response = client.call(:get_info_by_zip) do
  message USZip: zip
end
```